# I want to make a table appear, inside a PDF document, using Glen K Peterson's PdfLayoutManager TableBuilder

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox

Ok, I'll admit, it's almost the same as my previous question regarding Glen K Peterson's PdfLayoutManager's TableBuilder technique. I've managed to "draw" the table with Java code(finally, at long last), but how to actually make it appear in the PDF document??

Here's what I'm doing:

```
private static <T> List<T> vec(T... ts) { return Arrays.asList(ts); }

private void jBtnSalvareVerMetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jBtnSalvareVerMetActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    try {
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);
        PDFontLike font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("C:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\Oracle_Home\\jdeveloper\\mywork\\" +
                                                              "mywork\\project\\FisiereDLM\\" +
                                                              "FisiereAplicatie\\arial.ttf"));
        PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        contents.beginText();
        contents.setLeading(14.5f);
        contents.setFont((PDFont) font, 16);
        contents.newLineAtOffset(50, 725);
        contents.showText("Some text");
        contents.newLineAtOffset(0, -20);
        contents.showText("Laborator Metrologie");
        contents.newLineAtOffset(150, -60);
        contents.showText("Comanda verificare metrologica");
        contents.newLineAtOffset(12, -25);
        contents.showText("Nr: "+jTextFieldNrVerMet.getText() + "   Data: " + jTextFieldDataVerMet.getText());
        contents.newLineAtOffset(-160, -60);
        PdfLayoutMgr pageMgr = PdfLayoutMgr.newRgbPageMgr();
        final double pMargin = 40;
        LogicalPage logPag = pageMgr.logicalPageStart();
        final double tableWidth = logPag.pageWidth() - (2 * pMargin);
        final double pageRMargin = pMargin + tableWidth;
        final double colWidth = tableWidth/4;
        final double[] colWidths = new double[] { colWidth + 10, colWidth + 10,
                                                colWidth + 10, colWidth - 30 };
        final Padding textCellPadding = Padding.of(2);
        final TextStyle tipText = TextStyle.of(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 14.00, null);
        final CellStyle regularCell = CellStyle.of(CellStyle.Align.TOP_LEFT, textCellPadding, null,
                                                   BorderStyle.builder()
                                                              .left(LineStyle.of(Color.BLACK))
                                                              .right(LineStyle.of(Color.BLACK))
                                                              .bottom(LineStyle.of(Color.BLACK))
                                                              .build());
        Coord unu = logPag.tableBuilder(Coord.of(40.0, logPag.yPageTop()))
                          .addCellWidths(vec(120.0, 120.0, 120.0))
                          .textStyle(TextStyle.of(PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD_OBLIQUE, 12, Color.YELLOW.brighter()))
                          .partBuilder().cellStyle(CellStyle.of(CellStyle.Align.BOTTOM_CENTER, Padding.of(2),
                                                                Color.decode("#3366cc"), BorderStyle.of(Color.BLACK)))
                          .rowBuilder().addTextCells("First", "Second", "Third").buildRow()
                          .buildPart()
                          .partBuilder().cellStyle(CellStyle.of(CellStyle.Align.MIDDLE_CENTER, Padding.of(2),
                                                                Color.decode("#ccffcc"),
                                                                BorderStyle.of(Color.DARK_GRAY)))
                          .minRowHeight(120)
                          .textStyle(TextStyle.of(PDType1Font.COURIER, 12, Color.BLACK))
                          .rowBuilder()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.TOP_LEFT).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.TOP_CENTER).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.TOP_RIGHT).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .buildRow()
                          .rowBuilder()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.MIDDLE_LEFT).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.MIDDLE_CENTER).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.MIDDLE_RIGHT).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .buildRow()
                          .rowBuilder()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.BOTTOM_LEFT).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.BOTTOM_CENTER).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .cellBuilder().align(CellStyle.Align.BOTTOM_RIGHT).addStrs("Line 1", "Line two", "Line three").buildCell()
                          .buildRow()
                          .buildPart()
                          .buildTable();
        logPag.commit();
        TableBuilder tabelUnu = TableBuilder.of(logPag, unu);
        contents.showText(tabelUnu.toString());
        contents.endText();
        contents.close();
        document.save("C:\\Users\\Dragos\\Desktop\\Comanda de verificare metrologica.pdf");
        jLabelAverstismenteVerMet.setText("<html><center>Datele au fost salvate cu succes!</center></html>");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_jBtnSalvareVerMetActionPerformed
```

What I'm getting displayed inside the PDF document I'm creating, is a `.toString()` interpretation of the actual table I wish displayed(see the snippet below). I've looked everywhere inside Glen K Peterson's files, plus multiple other online examples of PDFBox table drawing techniques and I can't find any method or anything else, how to make the table appear inside the PDF document... please someone help me. =(

[image]

Comment: On the github page they show an [example usage](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/PdfLayoutManager/blob/master/src/test/java/TestManualllyPdfLayoutMgr.java) and an [example image](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/PdfLayoutManager/blob/master/sampleScreenShot.png) of what it produces perhaps you can run the example usage and analyze the code to see how the borders are shown on the example

Comment: Hi again David! =) Yes, that's what I've been doing until now, using that exact same example... the difference is that, I wish to create the PDF doc, with a button click, that also gets input text from text fields and saves those inputs inside the table.

Comment: then I'm confused. Your first step should be to get the table and borders to show, like the example on the github page shows... surely that works and then solves your problem? Then you can simply add whatever text you need?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do... the problem I can't overcome are the:            TableBuilder tabelUnu = TableBuilder.of(logPag, unu);
contents.showText(tabelUnu.toString());       lines. I'm just a beginner with Swing & Java, I'm not really that skilled yet! =( That's what I'm asking... is there any other way to go about this?